# Syntax highlighting output from external command below command line

Tags: vim

The following vim command executes an external command, and displays the output in the area below the command line in a plain text format -

```
:w !ls
```

I would like to be able to syntax-highlight this text. I know I can use -

```
syntax keyword Error foo
```

to create custom highlighting, but this doesn't seem to apply to the area below the command line.

The reason behind this is that I am running unit tests from within vim, and I would like to be able to highlight the output.

Apologies for not knowing what "the area below the command line" is called!

Comment: You can't highlight messages easily. The only way is capturing the output first with `system()` and then manually disassembling, highlighting, reconstructing and then outputting it again with `:echohl` and friends. Better use tmux and run tests in a separate window.

Comment: That area has no name, by the way.

Comment: The area with no name, spooky! Ok, I ended up writing a vim function that just reads the output into a new window, then vims syntax highlighting does the rest. Thanks.